# extracting (parsing) a string to pieces

Tags: php, templates

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  [{CONTENT:meta}]
  [{CONTENT:title}]
  [{CONTENT:head}]
</head>

[{CONTENT:open_body}]

    <p>[{LOCATION:main_1}]</p>
    <p>[{LOCATION:main_1}]</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I have the above `"template_file"` in a `$string`.  I am trying to do a loop that cycle through the string and on each iteration gives me the left side of the tag, the tag itself in a new variable, and then the right side in another string.  I can't use `str_replace` here because I need to extract what's inside of the tags before replacing them.

The output would be something like:

```
$string_left = everything up to a "[{"  
$command = "CONTENT:meta"  
$string_right= everything after the "}]".
```

I would then process data using the `CONTENT:meta` and then put the thing back together `(string_left + new data + string_right)` and then keep doing it until the entire thing was parsed.

Comment: You should probably use an existing templating engine instead of rolling your own.

Comment: What @Anon says. But if you want/need to roll your own: Do you have to use this syntax? Would it be an alternative to use a HTML-Like syntax for the template fields as well, making it possible to parse this whole thing properly using a DOM parser?

Comment: Or just dont use any template engine. PHP is itself the best template engine. You will always just replace one syntax with another one, just to pay additional complexity and performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a relatively simple regular expression:

```
$inputString = "left part of string [{inner command}] right part of string";


$leftDelim = "\[\{";
$rightDelim = "\}\]";

preg_match("%(.*?)$leftDelim(.*?)$rightDelim(.*)%is", $inputString, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

This will demonstrate how to use the regular expression.  The extra slashes in the delim variables are because your delimiters use regex characters, so you need to escape them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with a regex that matches `[{...}]`, along with a replacer function that takes the matched "command" and returns a suitable replacement string:

```
$output = preg_replace('/\[{([^}]*)}\]/e', 'my_replacer(\'$1\')', $string);
```

And define `my_replacer` as follows:

```
function my_replacer($command) {
  ...
  return $replacement;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a template software instead?  Here's a big list.

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/19-promising-php-template-engines/